# JAVASCRIPT VAR equal if multiple values

Tags: javascript

```
var position = prompt("position:");
var manager = ["John", "Alex", "Joe"];
var admin = ["Texas", "Jesus", "Rick"];
var tech = ["Nexus", "Thomas", "Fred"]
if (position == manager) {
alert("manager")}

if (position == admin) {
  alert("admin")}

if (position == tech) {
  alert("tech")
}

else {
  alert("Incorrect position")
```

}

I would like to ask how it is possible to this program work. When I will enter in prompt John I would like to get alert manager when I will enter in prompt Rick I would like to have alert tech etc...

And also if I will enter something what is unknown random value it will get me Incorrect position.

Also I would like to ask if there is way when I will enter in prompt for example jOHN or john it will work. I am total beginner in JS and coding.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), for example:

```
if (manager.indexOf(position) !== -1) {
    alert("manager");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (manager.indexOf(position) != -1) {
   alert("manager")
}
```